# How to use datamapper to return table entries as a json formatted string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, string, json, datamapper

Let's say I have a table, and I want to return the values for every entry in the table for a particular field. How can I use datamapper to return these values as a json formatted string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I getting it right?

```
Hash[Page.all( :fields => [:id, :title] ).map{|p|[p.id,p.title]}].to_json

DEBUG (0.000176) SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `pages` ORDER BY `id`
> {"1":"page A","2":"page B"}
```

Or, if you want an array

```
Page.all( :fields => [:title] ).map(&:title).to_json

DEBUG (0.000038) SELECT `title` FROM `pages` ORDER BY `id`
> ["page A","page B"]
```